# How $S_1$ & $S_2$ are equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

If $f\in L^{\infty}(E)$.

How $$S_1=\sup\left\{M:\mu(\left\{x\in E:|f(x)|\ge M  \right\}) \ne 0 \right\} $$ and $$S_2=\inf\left\{M:\mu(\left\{x\in E:|f(x)|\gt M  \right\}) = 0 \right\} $$  are equivalent?

> This is Herald Hanche-Olsen's answer
>
> If you put $$\begin{aligned}   f_1(M)&=\mu(\{x\in E\colon |f(x)|\ge
> > M\}),\\   f_2(M)&=\mu(\{x\in E\colon |f(x)|> M\}), \end{aligned} $$
>   then both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are (non-strictly) decreasing functions.
>   Furthermore, $f_1\ge f_2$, while if $M_1>M2$, then $f_1(M_1)\le
> > f_2(M_2)$. The result follows easily from these observations.
>   (Intuitively, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are practically the same function; they
>   differ only at discontinuities.

In this answer i'm not getting notion of introduction of infimum and
 supremum over $f_1$ and $f_2$?Also,if $f_1$ & $f_2$ are practically
 the same function then how the infimum of one can be equal to the
 supremum of other?

Answer (score 0):

If you put
$$\begin{aligned}
  f_1(M)&=\mu(\{x\in E\colon |f(x)|\ge M\}),\\
  f_2(M)&=\mu(\{x\in E\colon |f(x)|> M\}),
\end{aligned}
$$
then both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are (non-strictly) decreasing functions. Furthermore, $f_1\ge f_2$, while if $M_1>M2$, then $f_1(M_1)\le f_2(M_2)$. The result follows easily from these observations. (Intuitively, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are practically the same function; they differ only at discontinuities.

Comment: :Will you please explain how $f_1$ and $f_2$ are decreasing fuctions?

Comment: Monotinicity of measures: $A\subseteq B$ implies $\mu(A)\le\mu(B)$.

Comment: :But this is the condition for monotonically increasing?

Comment: :How can we introduce the notion of infimum and supremum over $f_1$ and $f_2$?Also,if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are practically same fuction then how can the infimum of one can be equal to the supremum of the other?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the time to explain at the level of detail you seem to require. But I will say this: If you make $M$ bigger, each of the two sets in the definition gets smaller (i.e., a subset of the original). And they're not supremums/infimums “over the functions”, but rather over certain sets associated with those functions. If you need more help, I suggest making an edit to your question, referring to my answer and explaining what it is about it you don't get. This will bump it to the front page, and perhaps induce someone else to explain further.